# Using the Draw tool with Screw modifier ISSUE

Tags: screw-modifier, splines, draw-mode

So I'm following Jamas tutorial on using the SCREW modifier with the draw tool, and It happens that at some point it goes bonkers.[image]

so if I'm drawing a line in edit mode close to the spline I already have, It draws just fine.
[image]

but once I draw just a bit outside the spline, it creates geometry WAY outside the spline

[image]
[image]
once I restart Blender this doesn't happen anymore and the draw works just fine.

Does anybody know why this might happen?

thanks in advance.
:)

Comment: a link to the tutorial might help. Providing your blend file might help.